# getting output with subprocess check_output

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this exe file "dexpt.exe" which returns a value but code below returns blank.Can any one help?

thanks
jayk

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import ctypes
tm=subprocess.check_output(['dexpt.exe'])
msgbox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA
mbx= msgbox(None,tm, 'Title', 0)
print mbx
```

Comment: Are you sure that the exe returns any output? What does `print tm` get you?

Comment: I see that you are new so i will tell you this: 
If someone helps you upvote their answer and accept the best answer :)
accepting is done by clicking the ✓

Answer (score 0):

This is how how to get the output and error if there were some but using `Popen`. This program calls a python script and returns the `error` if there was some ( you can easily modify it to return the `output`)
The `decode` method converts `bytestring` to `string`

```
def call_func():
    comand = "python test.py"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(comand.split(), shell=False,stdout= subprocess.PIPE,  stderr= subprocess.PIPE)
    if proc.wait() != 0:
        output, err = proc.communicate()
        return err.decode()
    return True
```